# Convergence of time-slice measures to convergence in law

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Question:
Are there some conditions that allow one to go from finite dimensional distribution convergence to convergence in path space?

Motivation: Consider a sequence of measures for e.g. solutions of the Fokker-Planck equation which are elements of $C([0,T];\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d))$, where $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ denotes the space of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let this sequence be compact w.r.t. the uniform topology in time and weak topology on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Is there any hope whatsoever (any tightness in path space) to show that this sequence would also converge in $\mathcal{P}([0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^d)$.

PS. I do apologise for the vagueness of this question.

Comment: Convergence of f.d.d. with continuity of sample paths seems, intuitively, to be enough.  The path space is separable, no?

Comment: Are you implying using Skorokhod's theorem? Its not clear to me how exactly should this work? Could you kindly elaborate.